# Is it possible to use "Spring Boot like" Environment abstraction with normal Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I try to configure my Spring application by `application.properties` files.
The default one will be in my `WEB-INF` directory, but I need also the opportunity to supply `--spring.config.location`.

Currently Spring doesn't even see `application.properties`.

It's something similar to "Spring Boot Externalizing Configuration".
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

How to achieve this in normal Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! Spring boot is using spring framework building blocks in order to provides you those features. In spring boot, [`ConfigFileApplicationListener`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener.java) is an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` that configures the context environment by loading
  properties from well known file locations. You can copy what they've done and have a boot like abstraction in your non boot projects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but practically it looks too complicated, because it requires Spring Boot specific events.

Comment: copy paste the whole boot project code into yours :)